# (C++) Why this program is giving the "0" or "nan" in the output?

Tags: c++, nan

I have this simple C++ program where I have to input the marks of 5 subjects and calculate it's percentage. But I have no idea why in the output it shows **"0"** and if I remove those **return 0** statements under input() and percentage() functions then it shows **"nan"** in the output.

> Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Marks
{
    float s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;
    float p;
public:
    float input();
    float percentage();
};

float Marks::input()
{
    cout<<endl<<"Enter the marks of your 5 subjects."<<endl;
    cin>>s1>>s2>>s3>>s4>>s5;
    cout<<"Subject 1="<<s1<<endl<<"Subject 2="<<s2<<endl<<"Subject 3="<<s3<<endl<<"Subject 4="<<s4<<endl<<"Subject 5="<<s5<<endl;
    //return 0;
}

float Marks::percentage()
{
    p=s1+s2+s3+s4+s5;
    p=p/5;
    cout<<p<<endl;
    //return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Marks student1;
    cout<<"Marks of student 1 are as follow:"<<endl<<student1.input()<<endl;
    cout<<"Student 1: Percentage = "<<student1.percentage()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

> And this is the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Not returning from a non-void function is undefined behavior. The result could be `nan`, it could be the right answer, it could be anything at all.

Comment: Technically the compiler could generate code that makes the computer place an order with Domino's for pizza delivery, but that's a lot more work than just doing nothing and letting the program go insane.

Comment: What is confusing about it showing zero when you return zero from the function and print it out?

Comment: Turn on your compiler's warnings.  Fix those warnings.

Comment: Please don't ever post code or error messages or program output as an image. Instead post *text*. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions are promising to return a `float`, but they don't. That is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). And once your program contains UB *anywhere*, it becomes meaningless in its entirety.